# GKTurnBasedEventListener could not be set to delegate of my ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

In objC the syntax written by [Rawendrich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5509/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-2) for `GKTurnBasedEventListener`, which was `GKTurnBasedEventHandler` there at that time, now changed by Apple is as below.

```
 if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

void (^setGKEventHandlerDelegate)(NSError *) = ^ (NSError *error)
{
    GKTurnBasedEventHandler *ev = 
      [GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler];
    ev.delegate = self;
};

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {     
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] 
     authenticateWithCompletionHandler:
      setGKEventHandlerDelegate];        
} else {
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
    setGKEventHandlerDelegate(nil);
}
```

Now after converting this to swift, and with the composition of writing down `GKTurnBasedEventListener` instead of `GKTurnBasedEventHandler`, this comes the following way.

```
//  Converted with Swiftify v1.0.6381 - https://objectivec2swift.com/
if !gameCenterAvailable {
return
}
var setGKEventHandlerDelegate: ((_: Error) -> Void)? = {(_ error:   Error?) -> Void in
    var ev = GKTurnBasedEventHandler.shared()
    ev.delegate = self
}
print("Authenticating local user...")
if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated == false {
GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticate(withCompletionHandler:    setGKEventHandlerDelegate)
}
else {
print("Already authenticated!")
setGKEventHandlerDelegate(nil)

}
```

Unfortunately this is not the right syntax to set delegate of `GKTurnBasedEventListener` for my `ViewController`.

Please if anyone of you could solve this for me, because without this I'm not able to read through event listener's default functions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after just about harsh 10 hours, I figured out this problem from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515575/5616993). Although this syntax is in objC, but there's no problem of converting it to swift from [Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main).

Although a bit later than the real time, but I'm now able to understand that setting delegate of `GKTunBasedEventListener` is not like the one we do for `UITableViewControllerDelegate`.

Here, one must have to first authenticate local player, then after you have to register local player's listener to the `ViewController`'s `delegate` GKLocalPlayerListener.

One other thing I found on [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayerlistener):
*Do not implement `GKChallengeListener`, `GKInviteEventListener`, `GKSavedGameListener`, and `GKTurnBasedEventListener` directly; implement `GKLocalPlayerListener` instead. You can listen for and handle multiple events using `GKLocalPlayerListener`.*

So then on I've implemented in the following way.

```
import GameKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,   GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, 
GKLocalPlayerListener {


..... 


func player(_ player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventFor match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) {

    print("#1")
    print(player)
    print("#2")
    print(match)
    print("#3")
    print(didBecomeActive)

    if match.status == GKTurnBasedMatchStatus.open
    {
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer() == match.currentParticipant
        {


        if didBecomeActive
        {
            // Active now
        }
        else
        {
            // Active already
        }

        }
        else
        {
            // It's someone's turn

            if match.matchData != myMatch?.matchData
            {
               // Match Data being Updated by Someone
                print(player.alias ?? "No Name:")
            }

        }


    }

    thirdTopLabel.text = match.matchID! + "\n" + didBecomeActive.description

}

....
```

Now in `ViewDidLoad()` function put the following code.

```
// In the ViewDidLoad function 
 if(!GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated)
    {
        authenticatePlayer { (auth) in

            weak var weakSelf = self
            weak var weakPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

            if(auth){


                 weakPlayer?.register(weakSelf!)
                 self.suthentication = true;

            }
            else{
                print("failed in authentication")
                self.suthentication = false;
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Already Authenticated
        GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().register(self)
        localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()


    }
```

And finally your Authentication function should be like this.

```
// authenticate local player :: Just Authentication
func authenticatePlayer(completionHandler: @escaping (_ resultedPlaces: Bool) -> Void) {

    localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()


    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
        { (viewController , error ) -> Void in
            if viewController != nil
            {
                self.present(viewController!, animated:true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                if self.localPlayer.isAuthenticated
                {

                    completionHandler(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    completionHandler(false);


                    print("not able to authenticate fail")
                    self.gameCenterEnabled = false

                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        print("\(error.debugDescription)")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print(    "error is nil")
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

**NOTE: `GKLocalPlayerListener` won't work on simulator.**

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you want a working example of how to use GKLocalPlayerListener during a turn-based GameKit match, you are welcome to take a look at this [example project for a turn based game](https://bitbucket.org/tenseg/hellogamekitios). I hope it helps to see all the pieces in context.